# The debugger not enter in the appDelegate

Tags: ios, view, compiler-errors, appdelegate

When I run the application I get this error:

```
 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<UIApplication 0x860fec0> setValue:
  forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant
  for the key view.'
```

I rewritten the class RootViewController and I remade the xib two times. For this reason I placed the debugger in the appDelegate, and I saw that in the method

```
 - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions;
```

does not reach even to enter and goes directly into the main producing the error SIGBRT. What does it means? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, one place I got the same error was, I created an outlet of a an object in the controller and then deleted it later. But that outlet was still existed in the "connection inspector".

So check if there is some connection still existing there with the name "view". It means you are trying to set the value the key "view" somewhere in your code which is non-existant..! So first place you can look for is the connections inspector..:)